# display = 'none' does not work in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to hide divA and show divB. If I click a button I want to hide divB and show divA. I don't want to use JQuery.

I have troubles hiding divA when the page loads. When I click the button, the divB is hidden correctly.

I added this in the beginning of the document

```
<script>
    var doNotShow= document.getElementById('divA');
    doNotShow.style.display = 'none';
</script>
```

The thing is, it does not work. The weird thing is that when later, I try to hide divB via a button click then divB hides as it should. The divA is after the javascript part in the file.

Comment: why not just set the css for `divA` to `display:none`

Comment: "The divA is after the javascript part in the file." <-- this is the problem. Put the script tag after the HTML part and it will work

Comment: Make sure not to use JavaScript to initially hide your element, unless it shouldn't always be hidden when the page load. Simply use a CSS rule like I (and @PedroEstrada) suggested. It's far more elegant and efficient.

Comment: Better yet, why not [*never* use IDs](http://oli.jp/2011/ids/) for styling and only use classes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I added this in the beginning of the document

You must execute `document.getElementById` **after** the element with the queried ID exists in the document, otherwise `null` will be returned.

You can move the script tag to the bottom of the page (or simply after those elements), or wrap it inside a [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload) handler.

---

It's good practice to have the `<script>` tags right before the closing `</body>` so all the elements are already present in the page and you don't need to worry about wrapping code in `window.onload` or DOM ready ([`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded)) handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Javascripts are executed when they are read. If divA is defined after the script, there is nothing to execute the script on, which you will see if you use debugging tools like Firebug in Firefox or Developer Tools in Chrome (a TypeError will occur).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is running before `divA` exists in the DOM. That's why it doesn't work.

To solve the issue with your current solution, put your script after the `divA` markup in the document.

However, you do not need to use JavaScript and probably shouldn't to initially hide your `divA` element. You can use the following CSS rule instead:

```
#divA { display: none; }
```